# How to sort string array when it contains int values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$files = array (
  '/test/tmp/file_7.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_9.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_11.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_1.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_3.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_12.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_13.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_10.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_5.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_2.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_8.sql',
  '/test/tmp/file_4.sql.gz',
  '/test/tmp/file_6.sql.gz',
);

echo "<pre>";
sort($files);
print_r($files);
```

When use `sort()` it gives output like following

```
Array
(
    [0] => /test/tmp/file_1.sql.gz
    [1] => /test/tmp/file_10.sql.gz
    [2] => /test/tmp/file_11.sql.gz
    [3] => /test/tmp/file_12.sql.gz
    [4] => /test/tmp/file_13.sql.gz
    [5] => /test/tmp/file_2.sql.gz
    [6] => /test/tmp/file_3.sql.gz
    [7] => /test/tmp/file_4.sql.gz
    [8] => /test/tmp/file_5.sql.gz
    [9] => /test/tmp/file_6.sql.gz
    [10] => /test/tmp/file_7.sql.gz
    [11] => /test/tmp/file_8.sql
    [12] => /test/tmp/file_9.sql.gz
)
```

But I want it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => /test/tmp/file_1.sql.gz
    [1] => /test/tmp/file_2.sql.gz
    [2] => /test/tmp/file_3.sql.gz
    [3] => /test/tmp/file_4.sql.gz
    [4] => /test/tmp/file_5.sql.gz
    [5] => /test/tmp/file_6.sql.gz
    [6] => /test/tmp/file_7.sql.gz
    [7] => /test/tmp/file_8.sql
    [8] => /test/tmp/file_9.sql.gz
    [9] => /test/tmp/file_10.sql.gz
    [10] => /test/tmp/file_11.sql.gz
    [11] => /test/tmp/file_12.sql.gz
    [12] => /test/tmp/file_13.sql.gz
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `natural order` algorithm : [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) :

```
natsort($files);
```

And use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the index. For example:

```
natsort($files);
$files = array_values($files);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. but not ordering the index then used `array_values` to reset the index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)  with [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
echo "<pre>";
natsort($files);
$files= array_values($files);
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```